# Centered fixed/anchored footer?

Tags: html, css

I've looked at some questions posted here but everything seems overly complicated for what should be such a simple task? I just want a footer that stays fixed at the bottom of the screen no matter how long the page is vertically. Everything works, except I can't get the footer centered, it always aligns left..? Thanks!  http://jsfiddle.net/n4xxj/

```
<body>
     <div id="content"></div>
     <div id="footer"></div>
</body>




div {
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
}

#content {
background-color: beige;
border: 1px solid;
height: 1200px;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 150px;
}

#footer {
background-color: lightgray;
border: solid 1px;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n4xxj/2/?

Comment: margin: auto; should be margin: 0 auto; and fixed position for footer is a bad idea. What will happen when the content overflows?

Comment: This website may help: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: @j08691 try changing this in the CSS panel: div {
    width: 960px; } to this div { width: 100px; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your HTML to wrap in a wrapper div

```
<div>   
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
 </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n4xxj/4/)

Comment: Haha, beat me to it, saw the comment notification too late, +1 because you were first and your solution is more simple than mine.

Comment: @HazardinCode: I guess that really is a "Hazard in Code" +1

Comment: thank you! that was a very simple solution :) so why does putting the content and footer inside a div suddenly make the footer line up centered?

Comment: Actually, the container div is centered, which makes everything inside it appear centered as well, they are actually aligned left, see my comment bellow with the IE fix, you can clearly see that i aligned everything in the container left. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Because your footer was inside body which had more width. Wrapping footer in DIV (with margin auto and fixed width) gives it different context in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you will need to encapsulate the interior `div`'s into a big #container `div` and add to it `margin: 0 auto;` to align it.

Please note for a complete fix you should also add this (it's a simple IE fix):

```
body { text-align: center; }
#container { text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; }
```

And of course the #footer will need to have `width: 100%;`

Also the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n4xxj/3/